# Distinguishing synonym hits from regular hits in elastic search

Tags: search, lucene, elasticsearch

We are using Elastic Search and as part of a requirement we want to be able to distinguish hits generated by the synonym filter from those that are not because of synonyms.

For example if we had a query such as:

(car AND red) AND (NOT ford)

With synonym: color <-> red

Then we want to know:

[the red car] is a simple hit.

But,

[the color of the car] is a hit caused by the synonym filter.

Our synonym filter is defined as follows:

```
        synonym_filter :
            type : synonym
            synonyms_path : synonyms.txt
            ignore_case : true
            expand : true
            format : solr
```

Since the synonym filter does its work by modifying the token stream at index time there might not be a straightforward way to do this. Perhaps by using the highlighting functionality there might be an algorithm.

I was wondering if anybody has experience with this kind of solution or if a clever solution exists for this requirement. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best solution would be to search content with synonyms separately from content without.

That is, if you are applying the `SynonymFilter` at index time, then index the content twice, once without synonyms, and once with synonyms (and possibly any other filters to facilitate a broader search).  You could then either run separate queries against the two fields, or you could run a single query with matches against the more direct field significantly boosted.